# Email dataframe as table in email body with MailR

Tags: r, sendmailr

I want to send the below table in the body of the mail. i'm using mailR package.

+

```
------------+---------------+------------+
|    date    |  device_type  |  platform  |
+============+===============+============+
| 2017-01-24 |    desktop    |  Website   |
+------------+---------------+------------+
| 2017-01-24 |    mobile     |  Website   |
+------------+---------------+------------+
| 2017-01-24 |    tablet     |  Website   |
+------------+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: check out the `pander` package.

Comment: I check but i got an error message: "Error in if (file.exists(body)) body <- readChar(body, file.info(body)$size) : 
  argument is of length zero"    body = paste(pandoc.table(df1, style = 'grid'))

Comment: someone can help?

Comment: can you give a reproducible example? i.e., give us the data frame you're using (in reproducible/`dput()` form) and the `pander/mailR` commands you've tried so far?